# Deserialize obj passed through webservice

Tags: c#

I have this situation: in a webservice solution I create a class (or entity) `Car` and, with Entity Data Model, I create its respective table on Db. Then I create a `GetCar()` webmethod that return an object Car serialized.

In a console solution I references the webservice and so I call the `GetCar()` webmethod getting the myCar result.

When I go to deserialize `myCar` through `Car` class, that belong to webservice reference, I have new object but its fields are empty.

Something like this..

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Service.Car));
Service.Car cr = (Service.Car)mySerializer.Deserialize(*myCar*);
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Please add the code of the `Car` class

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess, without seeing the structure of your Car class, is that the members of Car are not exposed as properties or are all readonly properties.

If you add your Car class to your question, we can get a better idea.